# Changing credentials on client-side for Basic Authentication on Flex

Tags: apache-flex, authentication, session, basic-authentication, active-script

I want to let the user automatically re-login in my Flex app, which uses Basic Authentication

By the way, I have noted this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490806/http-basic-authentication-with-httpservice-objects-in-adobe-flex-air), which is relevant, but does not address the question of logging out client-side.

For example, after user A logs in, user B comes to the browser, goes to the login screen (perhaps in a new tab)  and logs in.

This should mean that I send user B's credentials in the HTTP headers, and that since these are different from  user A's, the server notes the fact and creates a new and separate session.

However, Flex's HTTP proxy catches the header and actually ignores these new credentials.

Flex does offer a way to tell the server to logout, and the Flex login code could invoke this every time before sending credentials, but that seems like an ugly workaround.   I want to be able to do this client-side. I could also use a non-standard header for Basic Authentication (since I control the server-side Authentication as well), but that also seems like an ugly workaround.

Is there some way to simply end the session on client-side from Flex code? This is possible from JavaScript, for example.

And is there a way to directly work with cookies at client-side, as I can in JavaScript?

I understand that some of the limitations may be caused by security considerations, but all my communication is to the "home" server, so it should be possible to avoid the restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of asking a couple of different questions here.

You can't actually end a basic-auth "session" manually per se (at least not to the best of my knowledge); at best, you can authenticate against a kind of variable basic-auth realm, which may or may not work for you, but otherwise, you're sort of stuck with the first-authenticated session for the duration of the browser instance.  Generally not the best way to go, unless you're pretty sure the user owns the machine, or can be depended on to close the browser after each session.

That leaves at least two other options, then.  The first is to send in your credentials with an URLRequest object (the post you cited, which I wrote, shows how to do that), and to have your HTTP response hand back something indicating the credentials were accepted -- e.g., a GUID, maybe, generated and stored in some session table (in the database sense) on the server, perhaps.  Then on successive HTTP requests, you might send along that GUID in an HTTP header, or as a value in each GET or POST request (similarly to the way Facebook handles their API clients, for instance), check the timeliness of that value on the server, and if all's well, carry on.  To "log out," then, you'd simply send in a request to invalidate that GUID, perform the necessary cleanup on the server and inside your Flex app, and all should be fine:  the next user can sit down, log in, authenticate, and the process continues.

Another way would be to work with cookies directly.  The cookie mechanisms are actually handled mostly for you in Flex, though, since everything gets passed back and forth by the browser on your behalf.  For example, if you send in a URLRequest with a username and password, and the server responds with a cookie of any kind, each request you make thereafter will package and send the same cookie, so in most cases, all you need to do is parse the initial response from the server (to set the state of your Flex app), assume the continued presence of the cookie, and when it's time to log out, send a URLRequest to log out, kill the cookie on the server, on status=200 do your Flex-app cleanup, and so on.  Accessing the cookie values directly isn't the easiest thing in the world, though; you can use ExternalInterface as a proxy to JavaScript (examples of this online and here on SO, I'm sure), and get at them that way, but there's a good chance you don't even have to do that.

Hopefully that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Note also [this post](http://verveguy.blogspot.com/2008/07/truth-about-flex-httpservice.html), which details some of the incredible distortion that Flex adds to HTTP Requests.