# Send xml from ActionScript to PHP

Tags: php, xml, actionscript, handle

I have values inside an XMLList in Actionscript. Need to send these values to the DB and update it.
My actionscript code is as follows:

```
public static function saveUserPermList():void {

        var ht:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        ht.url = Config.getServerURL();
        ht.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        //ht.resultFormat = "e4x";
        ht.contentType = "text/xml";
        ht.request["action"] = "saveUserPermListXML";
        ht.request["pdata"] = Application.application.userPermListModel.toString();
        ht.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,AdminUserList.saveUserPermListResult);
        ht.send();
    }
    public static function saveUserPermListResult(e:ResultEvent):void {
        trace(e);                   

    }
```

1. How can I send the XMLList data to PHP? Should I add a toString() to it?
2. Also what should be the contentType in Flex.

How can I catch this inside PHP, pl let me know, trying to use, this way,

if($user -> isAllowedAccess()) {

```
    header("Content-type:text/xml");
    $postedData =  $_POST["pdata"];     

   // $xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($POST['pdata']);
   // echo($xmldoc);
```

}

No luck. Pl let me know.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, didn't get you. Posted the screenshot of the sourcecode to show what I am trying. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The `method` property of `HTTPService` should probably be "POST", and the `contentType` for the request itself should probably be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

On the PHP side, `$_POST["pdata"]` would then be a string containing XML markup. You could either save that in a database directly, or first parse it into XML (via `SimpleXML` or `DOMDocument`) and do something with the contained data.

PS: I've just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490806/http-basic-authentication-with-httpservice-objects-in-adobe-flex-air/1425045#1425045) that seems to shed some light on the internal behavior of the `HTTPService` class.

Comment: Content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is not working. Just want to know how to send a xml string from Actionscript to PHP.
The collection used in the code is XMLList.

Comment: @Vish: Have you tried installing a network sniffer and looking at the packets that go over the wire? Maybe that's the first step to debug the problem.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Thanks for the tips, actually tried another option.  Split the XMLList to create a string and then sent the string to PHP. In the PHP, used the explode function to get the contents. Works fine.

Thanks again.