# flash and htaccess issue?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, .htaccess

I have a flash swf application and the swf need the support of the .php files to get data. But my server folder is protected with htaccess and htpasswd. So the access from flash is not possible. How can I overcome this situtation?

Comment: Even if you could put the credentials in the flash file, that would just defeat the point of the protection completely, because the flash file could then be decompiled (it's not difficult) and the password revealed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a little proxy php script that gets the data from the protected files and sends that data back to flash.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Flash is not able to send credentials to the server, but as __dominic said, you would require a PHP script to login for you. This would act as a 'gateway' to your data, but the PHP script acting as the gateway would have to be in a non-password protected folder so Flash could access it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. See [other thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490806/http-basic-authentication-with-httpservice-objects-in-adobe-flex-air)