# How to call web service with basic authentication in flex

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, basic-authentication

I want to call web service which has basic authentication .
once url get authenticated then want to call particular service 
 example xyz()
which takes 2 parameter and return a flag .

Please help me ?

Thanks in advance............

Comment: Do you have a web service available or you wanna create the web service ?

Answer (score 1):

For basic authentication you have to encode your username and password in service call headers like this:

```
import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;
private function authAndSend(service:HTTPService):void
{
        var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        encoder.insertNewLines = false;
        encoder.encode("someusername:somepassword");

        service.headers = {Authorization:"Basic " + encoder.toString()};                                                
        service.send();
}
```

already discussed at [HTTP Basic Authentication with HTTPService Objects in Adobe Flex/AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490806/http-basic-authentication-with-httpservice-objects-in-adobe-flex-air)

Comment: Also make sure you use POST.  Auth headers get stripped if you try to use GET.

Comment: Thanks Adnan . I have used above basic authentication it works fine . But now I am facing problem in calling xyz() function from webservice . How to call xyz() ,how to pass the parameter . Please help .

Comment: You can change the `service.url` if you need to call another URL (I suppose you use **HTTPService**)